# What happens to rep earned while a user is suspended?

Tags: support, reputation, account-suspension

I just upvoted an answer that was posted by a user prior to their suspension and was wondering if they'll actually see that now, or when their suspension ends.

The only reference I could find was in the FAQ:

> Earned rep is re-instated. This may be different from the rep value at
>   the start of the suspension because your posts may have been upvoted,
>   downvoted or deleted during the suspension period, and some of your
>   votes may have been invalidated.

Which seems to suggest that they'll see an increase in rep when their suspension ends, but I wasn't sure if I was reading that correctly.

Comment: "Which seems to suggest that they'll see an increase in rep" it might be a decrease or no change at all ... basically there is a rep recalc after the suspension finishes.

Comment: I cannot contact you anywhere, except maybe the workplace, but this page seemed more suitable... I am so so sorry that you have been suspended, and your question deleted.  Be strong and distance yourself from this car crash. Come back in November, we'll be in a stronger and better situation to evaluate the CoC and how users have complied with it. Bear Hug, even if it's only virtual.

Answer (score 8):

> Which seems to suggest that they'll see an increase in rep when their suspension ends

I will repeat what you quoted, but with a bit of it highlighted:

> Earned rep is re-instated. This may be different from the rep value at the start of the suspension because your posts may have been **upvoted, downvoted or deleted** during the suspension period, and some of your votes may have been invalidated.

Of the three highlighted actions, only one ends up with increased rep and there may be a mix of all three.

This suggests that they'll see either an increase in rep, a decrease in rep or no change in rep (in case nothing got upvoted/downvoted/deleted - or that the aggregate rep increases == aggregate rep decreases).

Comment: Ah, that's what I figured. Do they still get notifications and see the breakdown in the reputation section of their profile during the suspension or is it hidden till the suspension ends?

Comment: Not sure. They probably do get notifications and the rep breakdown in their profile. But they don't see those changes until the suspension is over. (I would need to check in the codebase or test or find someone suspended where they have gotten upvotes during their suspension)

Comment: Deletion of a downvoted answer (iirc) reawards lost reputation.